# Azure website open ID (Http failed / Https work)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

My website uses Azure Active Directory to log people with `OpenId`.

When I try to go to my website with `https://mywebsite.com`, I have the Microsoft login page (because of the `[Authorize]`). I put my credentials and I'm in.

But if I go to my website with `http://mywebsite.com`,  I have the Microsoft login page, put my credentials and then I get an infinite loop of Microsoft trying to connect.

Can someone explain to me where that comes from and how I can access my website with both http and https?

Comment: Do you have a requirement that your site be available over HTTP?  Using HTTP with OpenId / OAuth opens you up to a man in the middle attack where the access token can be intercepted.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem last year when using Identity Server (which is open id connect too), maybe this will work for you too.  The problem ended up being in the underlying asp.net owin libraries, but there is a work around:

Add the following to your global.asax.cs file in your web project:

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // place holder to solve endless loop issue
}
```

**Update:**

When i created an MVC using the VS 2015 template, it wired up my Azure Active Directory for me fine - but I needed to go in and fix the reply urls.

If you go into the manage.windowsazure.com portal and find the Azure Active Directory for your application, verify the Reply Urls have the azurewebsites.net url you need.

For the demo app i first added the following:
https://SomeJunkApp.azurewebsites.net/

That caused an infinite loop when I typed in http://SomeJunkApp.azurewebsites.net/ ... notice: http no 's'.

So I went back in the the azure active directory and added the http://SomeJunkApp.azurewebsites.net/ as another reply url and saved.  That fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I've seen some people speaking about this solution and I tried it but nothing as changed

Comment: Bummer, that was an easy fix for me.  Can you add some more detail on how you implemented your site?  For example did you follow some blog post or just use the mvc template configured to go to azure, etc.  That may help.  I think the loop will be caused due to when the browser lands on a page that requires authentication it will return a 403 or 401 and send the user back to the login page.  How did you configure the AD application?

Comment: For this part, I just used the pattern offerd by Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise for MVC with organization authentification ! I never touched anything in the code it provided, just added `app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver();` and the Kento Cookie Saver package but nothing else ^^'

Comment: Ok, i was able to reproduce it.  I'll modify my answer to also include the fix i just made for it to work for me.

Comment: Thank you for making this test ! I've just tried to do the same but I still have the same problem :(

Comment: Can you open up the dev tools in your browser and look at the network traffic?  See what url is getting a 302 redirect back to the login.  That may help.  You may also want to make sure you've closed your browser and reopened it.

Comment: I get 302 from VM5786:1 and from my website with httpS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112517/discussion-between-jason-haley-and-mrpixel6).

Comment: Session_start had solved a similar issue for me when using open connect ID. My issue was infinite loop when using asp session state after getting authenticated.